# Showing virtual keyboard on Windows 8

Tags: c++, keyboard, windows-runtime

Is there a way to show virtual keyboard on Windows 8 styled apps programatically with c++?

I'd rather not have any XAML involved, since I'm using DirectX (even thought I guess they could be used together, but it is easier just to drop the keyboard support than to learn XAML and try to fit it in with DirectX).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean without user action, then the answer is no. See the Invocation and dismissal logic and User-driven invocation sections in [The touch keyboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465404.aspx)

[Microsoft has an Input: Touch keyboard sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Touch-keyboard-sample-43532fda) that demonstrates how to bring up the touch keyboard when the user move the input focus to a custom control. Note the sample does not implement TSF so there is no full input method support.

Update: the sample is updated for Windows 8.1. Old Windows 8 samples can be downloaded from http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-8-app-samples-3bea89c8

Comment: MS updated the page to 8.1, you can get the old samples from http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-8-app-samples-3bea89c8